# WAL streaming backups with barman - WAL archive: FAILED

Tags: postgresql, backup, barman

I am setting up a barman server to backup a remote PostgreSQL server and am digging my way through a bunch of FAILED messages I get on `barman check [pg]`

```
Server pg:
        WAL archive: FAILED (please make sure WAL shipping is setup)
        replication slot: FAILED (slot 'barman' not initialised: is 'receive-wal' running?)
        receive-wal running: FAILED (See the Barman log file for more details)
```

I have the following values (which I believe to make sure 'WAL shipping' is enabled) on the PostgreSQL server's `postgresql.conf`

```
wal_level = replica
archive_mode = on
archive_timeout = 60
archive_command = 'test ! -f /opt/db/backup/postgres/archives/%f && cp %p barman@barman-server.intern:/opt/barman/pg/incoming/%f'
```

what am I missing here to get this going?

---

Addition:

based on the comment by @jjanes below I tried to new versions of the `archive_command`

neither ...

```
archive_command = 'test ! -f vm-51150-0180.step.zrz.dvz.cn-mv.de:/opt/barman/pg/incoming/%f && scp %p barman@vm-51150-0180.step.zrz.dvz.cn-mv.de:/opt/barman/pg/incoming/%f'
```

... nor ...

```
archive_command = 'test ! -f barman@vm-51150-0180.step.zrz.dvz.cn-mv.de:/opt/barman/pg/incoming/%f && scp %p barman@vm-51150-0180.step.zrz.dvz.cn-mv.de:/opt/barman/pg/incoming/%f'
```

... have any effect on the FAILED status though unfortunately

Comment: You command looks wrong.  That looks like it was meant to be a scp command, not cp.

Comment: And your `test` doesn't make any sense, you should test the same destination you copy to, not some other destination.

Answer (score 0):

> receive-wal running: FAILED (See the Barman log file for more details)

And what did you *find* in the barman log file?

> replication slot: FAILED (slot 'barman' not initialised: is 'receive-wal' running?)

Replication != Archiving
I seem to recall that barman uses Replication to get hold of WAL files and your database *is* complaining about the "barman" replication slot.
The Archiving command is something *separate*.

> test ! -f vm-51150-0180.step.zrz.dvz.cn-mv.de:/opt/barman/pg/incoming/%f

To paraphrase one Inigo Montoya:

> That command you keep using; I do not think it does what you think it does..."

Does this command *actually* work?
I've never come across a version of **test** that could examine a file on a remote machine *without* going through a mounted file share.

I believe that **barman** is a third-party product, supported by what used to be "2nd Quadrant" (now "EDB"?).
Have you tried asking *their* opinion about *their* product?

Comment: 1.) yes, I am active with similar questions on the barman mailing list ... no solution yet from there neither ... 2.) as far as I know the `archive_command` actually **does play a role**. i.e. the target dir must match some setting on the barman server. I have to admit that I do not know much on conventional psql backup tools (which may be part of my problem) ... 3.) yes there is that `replication slot`FAIL as well. I was just starting from the top of the list (which may or may not the right approach) and haven't gotten to that issue yet.